# How to change output of portlet widget

Tags: yii, widget

I am working on a prject developed by Yii.

My work is to implement a template for it.
The developer used

```
$this->widget('SearchBlock', array(
         ));
```

to create a search block. But title of block is in a  tag.

How can I change the output of CPortlet widget in order to put  tag instead of  tag for title ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CPortlet adds tags around the block content. You should use CWidget instead if you don't want those tags or want to use your own tags. Just open up the widget class file - SearchBlock.php - and extend the class from CWidget instead of CPortlet. CWidget doesn't have a renderContent() method though, so you will need to change it to run() instead.

Also, you may need to replace the import CPortlet line with this line:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CWidget');
```